# podman builds and runs containers extremely slow compared to docker

Tags: podman

I created a cross compilation container image with build environments for different target platforms (bare metal arm core, MINGW/Windows, armhf/Raspberry Pi).

All the following was done under Manjaro Linux on an Intel NUC 8i7BEH. I was logged in as average user.

Building the image already reveals massive performance differences between docker and podman. On my rather low performance machine I see a docker build to run more than 6 times faster than the same task done with podman.

```
docker build - 4 min 36 sec
podman build > 25 minutes
```

Building my application for a single target then uses in average:

```
podman - 73 sec
docker -  4.9sec
```

A native build on the same machine needs 3 sec in average.

Starting the container image to build the app for 3 different platforms in sequence needs (average):

```
podman - 85 sec
docker - 13 sec
```

How can this massive difference in container performance be explained? And is there anything I can do to increase podman's performance, so that it gets at least into the same area as docker? I'd rather use podman than docker. I prefer the service-less setup podman provides as well as rootless containers.

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: You may want to take your questions to the podman developers. You can find information on where to contact them [here](https://podman.io/community/).

Comment: My guess is that _fuse-overlayfs_ may be a bit slow. Native overlayfs is faster. Support for using native overlayfs as an unprivileged user is available for Podman version >= 3.1 on a Linux kernel version >= 5.12

Answer (score 10):

Looks like the original poster got some help here: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/13226

tl;dr
Make sure you're using fuse-overlayfs rather than the VFS storage driver.

[image: get your storage driver name by running "podman info --debug | grep graphDriverName"]

Comment: fuse-overlayfs is faster than VFS but native overlayfs is faster than fuse-overlayfs.